# Hartl's Rails Tutorial - Replies Extension

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've been looking at some of the other answers on here, but it seems like they all miss the part of the implementation that specifies replies appearing *only* in the replier and replied to user's feeds. i.e. their implementations have the reply showing up on the feeds of followers of the replier.

I've been trying to implement a solution using a combination of a scope and a modification of the given SQL subselect. I'm having trouble as the feeds are not rendering properly.

My process for replies: Replies are classified as a post that starts with "@userid#-user-name-separated-by-dashes-instead-of-spaces". The microposts controller calls the model to scan its contents for a reply, and sets to_id to the user id number of the user that the reply is for. By default, to_id is set to 0.

Inside the User controller's feed def, I then call a scope for getting microposts whose to_id matches a passed in user's id. This retrieves all replies to the user in question. I then call the modified SQL subselect which only gets posts from followed user that also have to_id set to 0 - i.e. the post is not a reply.

I'm not sure if the implementation in the User model is correct (call the scope, then call the SQL subselect - perhaps this does not work with the way the view is designed?).

Currently, Users that are replied to are not seeing the replies. The SQL subselect seems to also be broken - users are not receiving posts from any users they are following. The single line I changed was

```
where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids} AND to_id = 0) OR user_id = :user_id"
```

from

```
where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id"
```

There's also an issue with my tests are not working. The tests are:

1. User 3 creates micropost in reply to User 1
2. User 2 follows User 3
3. Logged in as User 1, visit home page, expect micropost to show up
4. Log in as User 3, visit home page, expect micropost to show up
5. Log in as User 2, visit home page, expect micropost to not show up

The post appears on User 3's homepage when I do it manually, but for some reason the test fails (item #4). User 2's test passes, and User 1's test does not pass.

I've included only the code that I have modified. Everything else is according to Hartl's tutorial.

Microposts Controller:

```
def create
 @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
  if @micropost.save
   @micropost.set_to_id
   flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
   redirect_to root_url
 else
   @feed_items = []
   render 'static_pages/home'
 end
end
```

Microposts Model:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  scope :get_replies, ->(user) { where({ to_id: user.id }) }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true


  # Returns microposts from the users being followed by the given user.
  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                         WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids} AND to_id = 0) OR user_id = :user_id",
          user_id: user.id)
  end

  # Sets to_id
  def set_to_id
    user_name = self.content
    if user_name.index("-") != nil
      if user_name[0..user_name.index('-')].match(/@\S+-/)
        self.update(to_id: user_name[1..user_name.index('-')-1].to_f)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

User Model:

```
def feed
    Micropost.get_replies(self)
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
end
```

Tests:

```
describe "replies" do
        let(:second_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        let(:third_user ) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        let(:post1) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: third_user, content: "#{user_name_reply(user)}") }

        before { second_user.follow!(third_user) }

        it "should show the reply post on the replied to user's homepage" do
          visit root_path
          expect(page).to have_content(post1.content)
        end

        it "should show the reply post on the replier's homepage" do
          click_link "Sign out"
          visit signin_path
          fill_in "Email",    with: third_user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: third_user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
          visit root_path
          expect(page).to have_content(post1.content)
        end

        it "should not show the reply post on any other pages" do
          click_link "Sign out"
          visit signin_path
          fill_in "Email",    with: second_user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: second_user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
          visit root_path
          expect(page).not_to have_content(post1.content)
        end
      end
```

Application Helper:

```
# Returns the user name in correct reply format ex: "Michael Hartl" -> "@1-michael-hartl"
  def user_name_reply(user)
    downcased_name = user.name.downcase
    prefix_string = "@" + user.id.to_s + "-"

    # if there are no spaces
    if downcased_name.match(/\s/) == nil
      return prefix_string + downcased_name
    end

    # create a name string ex: "Michael Hartl" -> "michael-hartl"
    name_string = ""
    str_index = 0
    while downcased_name.index(' ', str_index) != nil
      name_string = name_string + downcased_name[str_index..downcased_name.index(' ') - 1] + "-"
      str_index = downcased_name.index(' ') + 1
    end
    name_string = name_string + downcased_name[str_index..downcased_name.length - 1]

    return prefix_string + name_string
  end
```

halp meh, please

Comment: too long, too complicated. It is hard to understand what question is about.

Comment: I realize that, it's probably not comprehensible for anyone who hasn't gone through the rails tutorial. I was hoping others working on the same problem would be able to help. Thanks.

Comment: I actually fixed my issues. Tests are still broken for some reason, but I ended up getting rid of the scope and just modifying the SQL subselect.